# Re-arrange the visual order of elements without changing the HTML

Tags: html, css, css-float, flexbox

I have the following html code:

```
<p>some text</p>
<img src="#" alt="image" width="200" height="250" />
```

I want to pull the text to the right of the image.

I can't find anywhere how to do this with regular CSS without changing the order of the html code.

I tried to use `float:left` on the image but that's only affecting html elements after the image.

What's the right approach?

To be more clear, right now I am getting this:

```
some text
_____________
|           |
|   image   |
|           |
|___________|
```

What I want is this:

```
_____________
|           | some text
|   image   |
|           |
|___________|
```

Comment: Why would you not just place the `<img>` before the`<p>`? Since you want it rendered before the text, it seems like it would make more sense to place it before the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch up the order

```
<img src="#" alt="image" width="200" height="250" />
<p>some text</p>
```

then float both the img and the p left

```
img, p {
    float: left;
}
```

OR

Keep the order and float both right:

```
img, p {
    float: right;
}
```

You will probably need to adjust the width of the element which contains these 2 elements, since it will float it to the far right side of it.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to keep the order that way?

Comment: I guess you could keep the order and float right. You'd then probably need to adjust the containing element.

Answer (score 4):

There is a simple way to re-arrange the visual order of elements with **CSS Flexbox**.

No changes to the HTML.

The flex `order` property is designed to re-arrange elements within the flex container.

[image]

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
p {
  order: 1;
}
img {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p>some text</p>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt="image" width="75" height="75">
</div>
```

In the example above, child elements of the flex container (`#container`) are aligned in a row, which is a default setting (`flex-direction: row`).

The default value of the `order` property is `0`, which means that elements will align in the order they appear in the source.

By giving the `p` an `order: 1`, it jumps ahead of elements with `order: 0`.

Alternatively, we could give the image an `order: -1`, putting it before the text.

Learn more about the `order` property [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36118012/3597276).